# Can I set multiple values of the same CSS property with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to programmatically set the CSS `cursor` value to both `-webkit-grab` and `-moz-grab`.  For example, in a stylesheet, it would be represented as

```
mySelector{
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
}
```

So here, the `mySelector` element has the cursor defined twice.  Webkit browsers use the first definition, Firefox the second.  I'm wondering if there is any way in Javascript to do the equivalent.  I realize I could set a class, but my question was more for curiosity's sake to see if it was possible, than to solve a real-world problem I currently have.

**Edit** To clarify - the CSS I've posted (albeit with a valid selector) DOES work in both browsers.  I'm just wondering if there's a javascript-only way to do this.

Comment: Note that in CSS you're really *not* setting the same property to multiple values. Only one of them will be recognized, depending on the browser.

Comment: At what point do you want to move from one to the other?

Comment: When you're directly setting properties on the style object, it seems that the browser lets you set "bad" values but then ignores them.

Comment: Yes, the code you are using will be interpreted correctly by Mozilla and WebKit browsers and ignored by any browser that doesn't recognise those values (eg. IE)

Comment: @sinisterfrog but on a webkit browser it actually **won't** work, because setting "cursor" to "-moz-grab" *after* setting it to the WebKit version will overwrite it; the property will be ignored.

Comment: Does it look ok in your browser at http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/ ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Didn't mean one after the other, meant both at the same time.  Question updated to clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking if you can use JS to set a custom cursor, or are you asking if you can use JS to set those values in the CSS? Or something else?

Comment: Not exactly what you wanted, but have you thought of putting vendor-prefixed CSS in it's own class, then just adding the class to the object with Javascript? Seems a little less hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I have seen is to simply test whether the an assignment of the values was successful. If you assign a value the browser doesn't understand, it simply ignores it. For example in webkit:

```
> d = document.createElement('div')
  <div>​</div>​
> d.style.cursor = '-moz-grab';
  "-moz-grab"
> d.style.cursor
  ""
```

So you can use that behavior to roll your own function:

```
var setVendorStyle = (function() {
    var vendor_prefix = ['-moz-', '-webkit-'];
    return function(element, prop, value) {
        // try unmodified value first
        element.style[prop] = value;
        if (element.style[prop] === value) {
           return value;
        }
        // try vendor prefixes
        for (var i = 0, l = vendor_prefix.length; i < l; i++) {
           var vendor_value = vendor_prefix[i] + value;
           element.style[prop] = vendor_value;
           if (element.style[prop] === vendor_value) {
              return vendor_value;
           }
        }
        return false; // unsuccessful
    };
}());
```

Usage:

```
setVendorStyle(element, 'cursor', 'grab');
```

This probably won't work for *every* CSS property, especially not with shorthands, but hopefully for the ones with simple values.

Comment: Not as tidy as I was hoping, but I was hoping for something that doesn't exist.  This seems the most robust though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the style using `style.cssText` property:

```
element.style.cssText = "cursor:-webkit-grab; cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:grab;";
```

Browsers will try to parse the value the same way they parse CSS and apply all the properties they can recognize. But I'd suggest to define these styles in a class and just add this class to the element instead.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can detect the browser and add the proper css. something like this:

```
if (jQuery.browser.mozilla)
    $('mySelector').css('cursor','-moz-grab');
else if (jQuery.browser.safari)
    $('mySelector').css('cursor','-webkit-grab');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making a web page on which I can drag items and I wanted to
include those nice grabbing cursors :D. I have tried 2/3 of the above
options, but they both didn't work.
Also I think the detecting browsers solution is not optimal/accurate enough.
**This is my solution:**

First the css file:

```
.item{
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.grabbed{
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;  
}
```

So, the standard cursor will be 'grab' for me. Make sure `.grabbed` is always further down in your css file than the standard class `.item`.

Finally, the js file:

```
        $(".item").draggable({          
        start: function () {
            $(".item").addClass("grabbed");//                
        },
        stop: function () {
            $(".item").removeClass("grabbed");
        }
    });
```

You can see that whenever I start dragging, `.grabbed` is added, so my cursor will be 'grabbing'.
When I stop dragging, the `.grabbed` class is removed and the cursor returns to 'grab'.